# How to reroute stdout, stderr back to /dev/tty

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, stderr, tty

I just ssh-ed to some remote server and found that `stdout` and `stderr` of all commands/processes I am trying to run in bash is redirected to somewhere.
So, I got following questions

How to detect:

1) Which file `stdout`, `stderr` is beeing rerouted in Linux?

and

2) And how reroute by default `stdout` and `stderr` back to /dev/tty?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just typing commands that should output to STDOUT and STDERR.

Comment: Is there anything relevant in .bashrc?

Comment: nope, everything and everywhere seems absolutely as standart ec2 ubuntu instance(it is ec2 instance, btw).

Comment: What do you mean by rerouteing here? Rephrase the question, Need more information. Anyone can route any output to some other tty.

Comment: I want to redirect all default STDOUT and STDERR back to controlling terminal(how clean Linux instance works just after installation).

Comment: can you edit your post to include a short use case that shows your logging in via ssh, executing a command that should produce a error, and a cmd that should produce some output (and include any output that does occur)? Good luck.

Comment: Its possible by `tee`ing to another terminal. See my answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A command that should do literally what you asked for in (2) is

```
exec >/dev/tty 2>&1
```

But I suspect that your analysis of the problem is incorrect.  It would be useful to see the output of `ssh -v ...` (where `...` is whatever arguments you typed in your original `ssh` command).

Comment: adding this to my fork managing loop did the trick to reset stdout.  I was sshing, running screen, and running a forking os patching perl script, inside of which newlines started acting like carriage skip to the next line without returning.  Mucho gracias for pointing out this command.

Answer (score 10):

The command:

```
ls -l /proc/$$/fd/{1,2}
```

will show you which files are open as stdout (file descriptor 1) and stderr (file descriptor 2).

Comment: very good! any idea how to relate ex.: `1 -> pipe:[16418291]` to a pid?

Comment: I just found, at /proc, the other pid with this! `0 -> pipe:[16418291]`

Answer (score 2):

An answer to your first question could be found in `/proc/self/fd`. It contains symlinks to the files (or other things, pipes, sockets, etc) that your bash instance is connected to.

```
root@mammon:~# ls -l /proc/self/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 21 02:18 0 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 21 02:18 1 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 21 02:18 2 -> /dev/pts/3
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 May 21 02:18 3 -> /proc/15529/fd/
root@mammon:~# ls -l /proc/self/fd < /dev/null
total 0
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 May 21 02:18 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 21 02:18 1 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 21 02:18 2 -> /dev/pts/3
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 May 21 02:18 3 -> /proc/15536/fd/
root@mammon:~# ls -l /proc/self/fd | cat
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 21 02:18 0 -> /dev/pts/3
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 May 21 02:18 1 -> pipe:[497711]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May 21 02:18 2 -> /dev/pts/3
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 May 21 02:18 3 -> /proc/15537/fd/
root@mammon:~#
```

In the first example, you can see the first 3 file descriptors (which are the standard output, input, and error, respectively) all point to my pseudo-terminal `/dev/pts/3`. In the second example I've redirected the input to `/dev/null`, so the standard input file descriptor points to `/dev/null`. And in the final example I've sent the output of `ls` to `cat` through a pipe, and the standard input file descriptor reflects this. As far as I know there is no way to find which process has the other end of the pipe. In all examples there is the fourth file descriptor that represents the handle that `ls` has for reading `/proc/self/fd`. In this case it says `/proc/15537` because `/proc/self` is in fact a symlink to `/proc/pid` where `pid` is the PID of the process accessing `/proc/self`.

Answer (score 1):

**It can only be done if your longing shell is started with a pipe to `tee` command with another console as a parameter.**

Let me explain.

If you are logging in `/dev/tty1` and someone else is logging in `/dev/tty2`. If you start your shell (bash) by following command all the STDOUT/STDERR will be rerouted/copied to another shell (`/dev/tty2` in this case).

```
bash 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty2
```

So, someone sitting in `/dev/tty2` will see all of your activity.

If someone logins shell is `/bin/bash 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty2` instead of `/bin/bash` It'll happen every time he logs in. But I am not sure login shell can be set that way.

If someone  reroutes all the output of your shell this way you can check it just by checking if any `tee` is running in background.

```
ps ax | grep tee
```

This will output something like

```
tee /dev/tty2
```